# CSS How to wrap text before last whitespace

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have some `div` with fixed width containing text in the form `1234 days ago (10/10/1900)`.

The text must wrap the date part `(10/10/1900)` ONLY if string is too long to stay on the same line

I tried to add a new line before the date and apply the rule `white-space: break-spaces;` but all string are wrapped

Any other attempts to use `overflow-wrap` or `word-break` doesn't work as I wish

Have you some idea? Below I show my example code

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.footer {
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: break-spaces;
}

.wrong {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.correct {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="footer wrong">1234 days ago (10/10/1900)</div>
<div class="footer correct">4 days ago (04/05/2050)</div>
</div>
<p class="wrong">The text "(10/10/1900)" must be wrapped<p>
<p class="correct">The text "(04/05/2050)" fits the line so isn't necessary to wrap<p>
```

Comment: '10/10/1900' looks to be wrapped in your example snippet. Could you clarify what you're expecting?

Comment: Your code works perfectly, except of course the description in the blue box is incorrect if the viewport is so narrow that the date has to wrap in the second box as well - run your snippet in full page mode on a wide enough viewport to see this.

Comment: @ChidiWilliams in my example only "/1900)" go to separated line instead I want all the date part plus the parenthesis "(10/10/1900)" go to separated line

Comment: @AHaworth The date pattern "(10/10/1900)"  in the red box must go to separated line instead only "/1900)" is wrapped

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. On my system, IOS Safari, the slashes are not being used as break points. What browser/OS are you on?

Comment: Firefox 98.0.1 desktop on macOS Monterey

Comment: Yeah, same for me. I was on Chrome which also wraps fine. I have added an answer which should resolve add support for Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the dates into `span` elements with `white-space` set to `pre`.

```
<span style="white-space: pre;">(10/10/1900)</span>
```

(Note that, if the date is wider than the container's 170px width, it will continue to extend past the box without wrapping.)

Comment: Wow! This works, the date wraps only if necessary. I'm trying to check the date does not grow beyond the container width

Comment: mmm, now works on FF but on chrome also the word "ago" is wrapped but there is space, this happens when the white space is placed inside the span

Comment: where is the space?

Comment: never mind, it's fine, BTW the space between the word "ago" and parens "ago (10" in chrome do not work if written "ago<span ...> (10/...)" instead of "ago <span>(10/..."), note the space inside span

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing "/" use the HTML entity `&sol;` which should prevent a breakup when pushing the date into the next line.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="footer wrong">1234 days ago (10&sol;10&sol;1900)</div>
<div class="footer correct">4 days ago (04&sol;05&sol;2050)</div>
</div>
```